# Fade page out on leaving url (as well as in on landing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fadein, onload

I have seen this effect [here](http://oneup.themes.tf/new-modules-in-v1-5/) - the page fades in on load and fades out on links... I have found code snips to do this.

The code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// the body is already set to display none!

$("body").delay(500).fadeIn(500);

$("a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    linkLocation = this.href;
    $("body").fadeOut(500, redirectPage);       
});

function redirectPage() {
    window.location = linkLocation;
}

});
```

... but what I can not figure out is how the page fades out and back in when you refresh the page in the [OneUp theme](http://oneup.themes.tf/new-modules-in-v1-5/) example above???

Might it be ajax??

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

I think it may be what you are looking for. Just make a function that fades out the page and you can call it when someone clicks away or refreshes.

Comment: Thanks @jordan... is there a way to allow the fadeOut to 'complete' before the page is refreshed?!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer... Go to the link, refresh the entire page. Watch the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/xom89ne6/2/

```
body{

display: none;

}

$(function(){
    $("body").delay(500).fadeIn(1000);
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        $("body").fadeOut(1000);

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @judson, the page may fade out (partially) in the fiddle, but there appears to be no way (at least from what I can produce) to allow the fadeOut to complete before the page refreshes... but there MUST be a way... it works on the oneUp theme?!?!